# "Go to home folder" button in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I try to find "go to home folder" button in QGIS 2.12, like in the ArcGIS. It returns the default folder to the home folder where the map located.

Comment: What does that button normally do?

Answer (score 4):

Using QGIS2.14 on Windows:

If you activate the "Browser Panel" from menu View | Panels, you will see something like:

[image: Browser Panel]

There you find "Home" tree but unfortunately it is not what you are looking for.
This "Home" in QGIS just suggests your User directory.

Instead, you can use **Favourites** to set your "Home" directory. Try right-click of your mouse, and you can add any desired folder as your Home location.

**[EDIT]** As your requirement is to go back to **the folder where the map (.mxd) is**, please choose the folder you have stored your project file (.qgs) as the **Favorites**. Then the folder acts same as the "Home" (ESRI-wise). Sorry I missed out this part.

Answer (score 3):

Using QGIS2.14.8 on Windows:

If you activate the "Browser Panel" from menu View | Panels, you will see something like:

[image]